# Setting UINavigationController's navigation bar and rootViewController in the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, rootviewcontroller

I am facing a dilemma trying to set a `UINavigationController`'s `rootView` UIViewController and `UINavigationBar` in the same time. It seems that a `UINavigationController` can be either initiated with a `rootViewController` as so:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: someViewController)
```

or with a UINavigatioBar, like so:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: someUINavigationBar, toolbarClass: nil)
```

However, I would like to be able to add a rootViewController as well as a custom `UINavigationBar`. Is there any way to do so?

I've tried setting the `UINavigationBar` like `navController.navigationController?.navigationBar = MyNavigationBar`
however, it seems that navigationController?.navigationBar is only a getter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `rootViewController` is just the first view controller to be displayed. While it seems to be inaccessible from nowhere you can just set the `viewControllers` stack property to one view controller, your root.
Here is an extension with a convenience initializer.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    convenience init(navigationBarClass: Swift.AnyClass?, toolbarClass: Swift.AnyClass?, rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        self.init(navigationBarClass: navigationBarClass, toolbarClass: toolbarClass)
        self.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just set the rootViewController after creating the `navController`?

```
let navController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: someUINavigationBar, toolbarClass: nil)
navController.viewControllers = [someRootViewController]
```